# Why is Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit lagging horribly in a VM (VM Player)?

Tags: 10.10, vmware, virtualization

I am currently running a VM of Ubuntu 10.10 within VMware Player (host & vm stats below) and I'm getting horrific lag. I've executed the initial setup of the vmware files but nothing beyond that. I'm not really sure where to go from here and any help would be awesome.

The weird thing is, its not laggy all of the time. Occasionally it'll be snappy as if it were host OS. I can't place the rhyme or reason as to why it would act that way sometimes and not others.

**Host**

- Windows 7 x64 Ultimate SP1
- Intel Q6600 (quad core cpu)
- 8 gb ram
- 4 x 500gb 7200RPM drives in Raid 10

**Virtual Machine**

- Ubuntu 10.10 x64
- VMware Player v3.1.3
- 3gb memory (reduced from 6 gb memory in hopes it was just a paging issue)
- 100 gb flexible drive out of a 120 gb  partition

Comment: why not just install it locally?

Comment: @Roland Taylor I develop for both .Net & Rails so it makes it nice to have the ability to swap back and forth. Besides, I have to run Ubuntu in VM on my laptop (HP Envy 17) because of horrible driver support with the laptop altogether.

Comment: I think VMware Player lacks certain features. You might need the VMware proprietary version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a good start to solve your problem would be to pinpoint exactly what's going wrong. May I suggest that you use tools such as top, free -m and iotop on your host to find out if it is the CPU, the memory or the IO that's causing problems? Once you have a better idea of what your bottleneck is, assuming that there is one, then it'll get easier to find out how to solve it.

Comment: I'll go this route and mark it as the answer. Hopefully I can track it down, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Online benchmarks suggest otherwise, but in my experience, VMWare is just horrible for IO performance.  Maybe the issue is that IO bandwidth is good, but everything else lags while it does the IO.  Try VirtualBox; you'll probably find it's MUCH better.

Answer (score 1):

Also, but probably not the full-answer, would be that you install the thing to the VD, or else you are sitting there on a live boot...